# Where can I find black owned small businesses that did not receive PPP loan?

Tags: data-request, business

I'm building a heat map of PPP loan data comparing black-owned small businesses that did not receive PPP loans vs white large businesses that received and returned the PPP loan. Then, analyzing the returned PPP loan time frame against minority-owned business closures in major cities. The results should be interesting!